# App is stuttering after picking ~7 images to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-bitmap, image-compression

I am creating an application where users can, among other things, create photo albums.
Each album can contain max. 20 photos or videos.
The problem is that when in the Activity where the user selects photos, after user selects ~7 photos (I think the amount depends on the amount of RAM) and these photos are added to RecyclerView, then the application starts to stutter. If I select 20 photos (max) then the app horribly stutters but does not crash.
I thought to compress the photos before they are added to RecyclerView with this code:

CompressImage.java

```java
    @Nullable
    public static Bitmap FromFile(Context context, @NonNull String filePath, @NonNull CompressFor compressFor) {
        if (compressFor.equals(CompressFor.LOCAL)) {
            bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESS_THRESHOLD, out);
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of original image: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, bmp1.getByteCount()));
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of image: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, out.toByteArray().length));
            Log.d(TAG, "Compress Threshold: " + COMPRESS_THRESHOLD);
            Log.d(TAG, "----------------------");

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        } else if (compressFor.equals(CompressFor.DATABASE)) {
            throw new NotImplementedError();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void Recycle() {
        if (bmp1 != null) {
            bmp1.recycle();
            bmp1 = null;
        }
    }
```

MediaPickerAdapter.java (for RecyclerView in Photo picker activity)

```java
String imagePath = GetPathFromUri.getPath(mContext, (Uri) mImage.get(position).get("imagePath"));

Bitmap image = CompressImage.FromFile(mContext, imagePath, CompressImage.CompressFor.LOCAL);

Glide.with(holder.recent_photos_iv)
                        .load(image)
                        .into(holder.recent_photos_iv);
CompressImage.Recycle();
```

And then with LogCat I checked the size of images in RecyclerView

```java
Log.d(TAG, "Size of original image: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, bmp1.getByteCount()));
Log.d(TAG, "Size of image: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, out.toByteArray().length));
```

Size of original image (not in RecyclerView & recycled after compressing): 5,8 MB

Size of compressed image (in RecyclerView): 29 KB

After I added 8 compressed photos into RecyclerView I dumped memory heap in Android Studio Profiler and it shows that Bitmaps (in general) takes ~214 MB:
[image: Heap Dump]

before picking photos to RecyclerView Profiler shows that Bitmaps takes ~107 MB of memory.

So I think correctly that 8 compressed images, which one weighs 29 KB, in memory occupies ~107 MB?

The issue for myself is strange. After compressing photos, the app still stutter after selecting ~7 photos.
The problem is new to me because in the same application in another Activity I also have a RecyclerView that loads about 20 photos from Firebase (I think at full resolution because I don't compress them) and there the application does not stutter.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Delete `FromFile()`. You are wasting a ton of heap space and CPU time decoding an image twice, and you are not actually changing anything useful -- your second `Bitmap` will take up the same heap space as will your first `Bitmap`. Instead of decoding twice, decode once, using `inSampleSize` on `BitmapFactory.Options` to have `BitmapFactory` downsample the image. Better yet, use an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso, and it will handle `inSampleSize`, background threading, etc. for you.

Comment: FWIW, I cover `inSampleSize` in the "Issues with Application Heap" chapter of [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/). And, I cover the use of Glide in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-internet-003) of [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).